# how to use some variables defined in one fucntion in another function?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have a function defined as below:

```py
def mod2():
   while true:
       I = raw_results[0]
       Q = raw_results[1]
```

Now I want to define another function `def plot_mod()` to plot this I,Q. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd pass the I and Q as parameters to the `plot_mod()` function.

Ignoring the `while true:`

```py
def mod2():
    I = raw_results[0]
    Q = raw_results[1]
    plot_mod(I, Q)
```